# Как перенести wordpress на PostgreSQL

Tags: wordpress, postgresql

Подскажите как лучше всего перенести `mysql` на `postgresql`?

Мой сайт на `wordpress` с плагинами, которые также взаимодействуют с базой. Будут ли работать плагины после переноса? Каким образом происходит сам перенос содержимого бд? Какие скрипты вордпресса придется редактировать?

Comment: Зачем это делать?

Comment: Не надо этого делать. WordPress официально несовместим с PostgreSQL. Вот инструкция, как подключить PostgreSQL к старой версии WP: https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5bcf8be364de8e00aa32d62b/wordpress-na-postgresql-5d19396e122da300aff83d68 Гарантий работоспособности нет.

Comment: @WPPunk хороший вопрос. Я ещё не видел сайта, где ускорение базы дало бы решающий прирост в производительности. Оптимизация кода в плагинах, правильное объектное кеширование - да. Но не движок базы.